# UITableViewCell newline characters

Tags: iphone, uitableview, newline, return

Is there any way to get newlines to be converted to actual linebreaks in UITableViewCell?

Right now they show up as \r\n (they come from a sqlite3 db) and just get displayed as such.

If I search and replace \r\n with actual return characters then it works fine, but I'm wondering if three is a proper way to do this?

Please don't suggest using other View types, the app is basically 100% complete save for this last bug and I don't want to re-test everything.

thanks
T

edit: Solution in case anyone has a similar issue:

```
cellText = [cellText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\r\\n" withString:@"\n"];
```

Olaf got me on the right path, thanks.

Comment: Read this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699678/append-a-newline-to-an-nsstring)

Comment: Solution in case anyone has a similar issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC on the Mac newline is \n, but this is not the question.

If you are seeing  the four characters "\r\n" on the screen then I assume the string coming from db is escaping the backslashes. Thus when you do the manually rewrite the (escaped) string `\\r\\n` is converted into `\n`.

The standard cell is using an embedded UILabel anyway, so rewriting your cell with a custom cell using another UILabel would not change much. ;)

Comment: Even though textedit/textmate see it as \r\n, xcode is reading it as \\r\\n so that was the trick thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished fixing this very issue in my code using:

```
myString = [[myString 
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\n" withString:@"\n"] 
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\r" withString:@""];
```

Hope that helps